# How do I get the time when the Location has been updated in Android?

Tags: android, geolocation, android-sdk-2.1

As you know we can get thast Last Known Location, but how do we get the time when that has changed?

Comment: Do you mean the last time the lat/lon values changed or the time of the fix that represents the last known location (Location: getTime())?

Comment: Probably a language barrier issue that I don't understand both path of your question. I don't care about the date when the location changed, I just want to know the current location how old is, when was last time measured even if stayed the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the getTime() method of the Location object.